# How to check time difference between two events

Tags: complex-event-processing, cumulocity

How to check time difference between two events. can someone suggest me the approach to do this?

I have different events coming from a device. initially it will be sending "started" event and after sometime it will send "completed" event. I need to calculate the difference in the start and completed event. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In CEP events the time variable is of java type Date so you can use something like:

```
d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()
```

and you have the difference in milliseconds

Comment: @TyrManz can you provide a sample query. I am also facing with similar scenario. I am new to cumulocity and cep. I also need to identify if the starting and ending events is from same device.

Comment: @rajmohan You can find quite some Cumulocity examples here: http://cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/advanced/. Take a look at contexts for how to process depending on the device. I can also recommend the following page from esper: http://www.espertech.com/esper/solution-patterns/. It has a lot of examples how to solve certain tasks with esper in general